# Word for person who loves to share knowledge

Tags: single-word-requests, synonyms, compliment

What is a word for a person who loves to share knowledge? So far I have *educator* in mind. Is there any other word?

Comment: How about "Teacher"?

Comment: Guru, Professor, Master - all of them should fit well depending on the regional and circumstantial context.

Comment: **loves to share knowledge, whether anyone wants to hear it or not** ... a blowhard

Comment: In the Christian world an evangelist. I've never heard a complaint about using the word outside of Christianity by Christians. IE a health food evangelist.

Comment: A "teacher" may share knowlegde, but he doesn't necessarily love to do it. There are surely teachers who hate their jobs. Likewise we do not normally refer to anyone who shares knowledge as a teacher. Like if my neighbor excitedly tells me all about yesterday's football game, he is sharing knowledge and he loves to do it, but we wouldn't call him a teacher.

Comment: @Wayne: "evangelist" is used fairly often these days in non-theological contexts. I've seen the term "Java evangelist" used regularly for people who promote the Java programming language. Sun referred to some of their Java advocates as "Java evangelists" as if it was their job title. (Maybe it was.)

Comment: Annoying Know-it-all =)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

How about "maven"? According to [the Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maven),

> A maven (also mavin) is a trusted expert in a particular field, who seeks to pass knowledge on to others.

[Admittedly, [many dictionaries](http://onelook.com/?w=maven&ls=a) define the word merely as something like "an expert", but the meaning is in flux, and the "person who loves to share knowledge" meaning is getting more common.]

Comment: Thanks @ShreevatsaR. Yah it is more closer to knowledge sharing.

Comment: Again, I must point out this was just a tentative answer; "maven" in most contexts just means "expert" or "self-styled expert" etc. — look up the dictionaries.

Comment: Although I don't have a good answer for the question, I don't think "maven" is understood by many English speakers.

Comment: @Shinto is right. And so is @ShreevatsaR. To my ears, maven has a mildly negative connotation which derives from the "self-styled" part. (Anyone can be a self-style expert.)

Comment: That _describes_ me! :D

Answer (score 7):

A [pedagogue](http://www.oxfordadvancedlearnersdictionary.com/dictionary/pedagogue) likes to teach others things.

Comment: Pedagogue has a rather negative connotation, though.

Answer (score 6):

A few more words for people who share knowledge:
teacher,
"teaching assistant",
tutor,
mentor,
coach,
guru,
contributor,
author,
polyglot,
blogger,
Wikipedian, ...

Comment: ... pedant ... (evil grin)

Answer (score 6):

How about "pundit"? A pundit is

> a person who knows a lot about a particular subject and who often talks about it in public

From: https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/pundit

Comment: I'd think pundit has a derogatory meaning.

Answer (score 5):

In addition to the excellent answers previously given with positive connotations, I offer this pejorative one:

```
pedant
```

...because loving to share your knowledge doesn't always mean others love to receive it.

That's not intended as a subtle dig at StackExchange users. I just really like the word.

Answer (score 2):

Within religion and technology people who are keen to spread ideas are know as [evangelists](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/evangelist).

["The Greek word εὐαγγέλιον originally meant a reward given to the messenger for good news".](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evangelism)

For evangelists who are promoting knowledge of a certain type of technology or religion, spreading the 'word' is seen as it's own reward, rather than seeking any monetary reward.

Answer (score 1):

A fountainhead is a person who is a source of all kinds of knowledge.  S/he may not love sharing that knowledge, however.

On the other hand, why would a fountainhead deliberately dam up the works by refusing to share knowledge?  Besides, isn't the job of a literal fountainhead to benefit all the people who congregate around it?  How could a fountainhead of knowledge not love benefitting others?

Yeah, fountainhead is an apt word to describe someone who loves sharing knowledge.

Comment: Doesn't fountainhead mean "source"?

Comment: @Pacerier: Yes. I'd say it's a metaphorical synonym. Jesus, for example, was a fountainhead of both knowledge and wisdom, and he evidently loved spilling over, as it were, into the lives of others with what he called "living water." See John 4:10 ff., and 7:37-38. Part of his modus operandi was to tell stories about people with whom his audience could identify and draw spiritual lessons from. He called these stories, "parables" (literally, "words alongside," which underscores the importance of applying his words to our lives by laying his words alongside our lives & then applying them). Don

Answer (score 1):

A professor is someone who professes his knowledge or faith, gratuitously, sometimes. To all who would listen.