# Opposite of "summarize"

Tags: expressions, antonyms

I want to indicate that some text has been made longer while emphasizing that no new content has been added.

Desired usages:

> I need to anti-summarize this paper to reach the ten page minimum.

or

> I can't believe the manager just anti-summarized my two paragraph
>   email into a 35 minute meeting.

Comment: [General reference](http://thesaurus.com/browse/summarize)

Comment: expand, but this is GR

Comment: @KateGregory It isn't easy as GR. Try it yourself. *Expand* is exactly what the OP does not want.

Comment: If this question is classed "off-topic" because the answer can be found in general references then I shall expect to see all requests for single-words in the future to be classified as such. I would also expect the same for this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121518/english-word-for-taking-a-derogatory-term-and-owning-it-with-pride/121523#121523) and this [one](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/word-for-person-who-loves-to-share-knowledge) and this [one too](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121714/is-revelationary-a-word-in-the-english-language).

Comment: The title of the question "the opposite of summarize" could mislead one into thinking that the answer is to be found in a thesaurus, but not for one moment did I do that. The question itself was detailed, had a context, and the OP had clearly done some research beforehand moreover, I wasn't convinced by jwpat7's suggestions so, I decided I to offer my answer. Method: I start off with an idea and then I check with a dictionary, if the definition matches my thinking then I post the link. This was a question that required thought. Six upvotes seem to confirm that impression too.

Comment: meta: GR? No. The antonyms for *summarize* generally listed on thesauri are firstly, broader in their scope, and furthermore, they do not in anyway suggest that merely 'a process of summarizing is reversed' -- it is just not possible to derive that sense from any of those words by any logic.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[***Stretched out***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/stretch+out): *to extend, force, or make serve **beyond the normal or proper limits**; strain: to stretch the imagination; to stretch the facts; to stretch food to feed extra guests; to stretch money to keep within a budget*.

> I need to **stretch out** this paper to reach the ten page minimum.
>
> I can't believe the manager just **stretched out** my two paragraph
> email into a 35 minute meeting.

[***Extend***](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/extend?s=t): *to increase the length or duration of; lengthen;*

> I need to **extend** this paper to reach the ten page minimum.
>
> I can't believe the manager just **extended** my two paragraph
> email into a 35 minute meeting.

Comment: The antonyms generally listed on thesauri are firstly, broader in their scope, and furthermore, they do not in anyway suggest that merely 'a process of summarizing is reversed' -- it is just not possible to derive that sense from those words by any logic.

Answer (score 5):

Adding new material that only confers bulk and no substance can be described as *padding*. This works both in physical and figurative senses.

> I need to pad this paper to reach the ten page minimum.

In your second sentence, where the form of expression changes, I don't think *pad* works. From least negative to most negative, you could use *expand*, *[inflate](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/opposite-of-summarize/121636#121636)*, *[stretch out](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/opposite-of-summarize/121641#121641)*, *[blow up](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/121632/opposite-of-summarize/121641#121641)*.

Answer (score 4):

how about ***elaborate***

in the sense of v. to add details to, or expand?

Answer (score 3):

*[Inflate](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/inflate#Verb)* (“To enlarge an object by pushing air (or a gas) into it; to raise or expand abnormally”) seems quite suitable.  Also consider  *[swell](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/swell#Verb)* (“To cause to become bigger”),  *[puff up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/puff_up)* (“To inflate with air”), and  *[blow up](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/blow_up)* (“To inflate or fill with air”).

Answer (score 1):

*Expound on* or *expound upon*: This comes to mind for use in a situation where one wants to add considerable detail to information provided in a summarized form.

For example, I would like to expound on the information provided in this email.

Answer (score 0):

I often use [embellish](http://www.chambers.co.uk/search.php?query=embellish&title=21st) in this situation, although it's not always appropriate as it somewhat depends on the nature of the additional content.  I think it would sit better in your second example rather than the first.

If a more colloquial option is sufficient then "flesh out" may be what you're looking for.

Comment: +1 for words «Opposite of “summarize”», but note that neither *embellish* nor  *flesh out* satisfies the “emphasizing that no new content has been added” portion of the question.  Both terms suggest additional detail or explanation.

Answer (score 0):

The word I recommend is **dilate**. *Merriam-Webster's Collegiate Dictionary*, Eleventh Edition (2003) gives two relevant meanings of *dilate* as a transitive verb:

> **1:** *archaic:* to describe or set forth at length or in detail **2:** to enlarge or expand in bulk or extent

And *The American Heritage Dictionary of the English Language*, Fourth Edition (2000) offers this intransitive meaning of *dilate*:

> **2.** To speak or write at great length on a subject; expatiate

There is something a bit odd about these definitions. Evidently, you can say "I must dilate my paper to reach the required ten-page minimum length" without being archaic, but only if you mean *dilate* in the sense of "to enlarge or expand in bulk or extent." If you mean *dilate* in the sense of "to describe (or say) or set forth (or write) at (great) length or in detail" without being archaic, you have to speak intransitively: "I must dilate on the subject of my essay, to reach the required ten-page minimum length."

Answer (score -3):

*[de-summarize](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22de-summarize%22&lr=lang_en)*

> Are there techniques explored to **de-summarize** the text? - Quora

[Revolution Analytics' R](http://www.inside-r.org/packages/cran/pathClass/docs/desummarize.ranks):

> **Desummarize** the GeneRanks which were previously calculated for each node in the underlying biological network back to the corresponding probesets for the Reweighted Recursive Feature Elimination (RRFE).

The antonyms for *summarize* generally listed on thesauri are firstly, broader in their scope, and furthermore, they do not in anyway suggest that merely 'a process of summarizing is reversed' -- it is just not possible to derive that sense from any of those words by any logic.

The only possible unambiguous and exact-fit expression for the OP's requirement would be *de-summarize* as used in contexts where, technically, 'to undo/reverse a summarization' is meant.

Comment: That’s a funny way to spell *winterize*.