# Is "revelationary" a word in the English language?

Tags: etymology, is-it-a-word

Is "revelationary" a word in the English language?.

If it isn't a word in proper English, then which word, if any, can be used for something that leads to a revelation?

Comment: Have you tried a dictionary. You'll quickly find out if "[revelationary](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/revelation)" exists. Could you tell us something about the context?

Comment: I was looking for something that could expound on the feeling  related to thespian arts and drama.... like catharsis and something that leads to revelation... in this case, as told by @bib 'revelatory'.

Comment: I find it interesting that the top related question to this one is: [If I invent a word, what language is it?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/1990/if-i-invent-a-word-what-language-is-it?rq=1) . Who knows, perhaps that fact is even revelationary. ;-)

Comment: @Mari-LouA: That is not necessarily true. Even the best dictionaries don't have every possible affixation possible; ther are just too many possibilities. 'nonneologistically' is definitely a word formed by grammatically allowed prefix and suffix processes. But it is not in any dictionary I could find online or off.

Comment: @Mitch I just checked with google, instead of using an online dictionary and it appears "revelationary" does  exist.http://www.wordnik.com/words/revelationary and http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/revelationary with the exact meaning the OP was looking for. On my spell checker there are red wriggly lines but... I would never have said so.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: there are all sorts of things that sow up in a regular manner in nGrams, for example lots of misspellings. Do you claim that misspellings are words? Do you claim that letter sequences not mentioned in a dictionary but are legal combinations are not words? Also, wiktionary isn't a trustworthy source of consensus (yet?) to the extent that wikipedia is. Wordnik...well, I commend them and what they're doing but I'm not sure yet, they're kinda new.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: which is to say, the high school English teacher in me says that 'revelationary' is a word that people commonly make up because they can't remember (or haven't the experience of) 'revelatory' and it would be marked in red. As wrong.

Comment: Agreed but would you not castigate the teacher who instead of correcting, said. Close, enough. So many people make that mistake it's becoming acceptable and for some academics it is considered a dialect (if proven that a "misspelt" word had a high frequency rate in one particular region). There's a fine line, is all I can say.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You may be looking for *[revelatory](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/revelatory?showCookiePolicy=true)*

> of or relating to a revelation

Answer (score 0):

While *revelatory* may be the technically correct word in most circumstances, what struck me most strongly about *revelationary* was its homophonic resemblance to *revolutionary*. I can easily imagine an author choosing *revelationary* in certain circumstances in order to create this homophonic effect for the reader.