# Word / Phrase request for someone who loves to propagate education among others

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, translation

I am looking for a English word or phrase which suits someone who love to propagate education among people by establishing educational institutions or writing books and so on.

In order to translate a text from my mother tongue to English I need such a word but I can not find it so far as I have knowledge about English.I have tried to use some words(for example devoted) for this purpose but they seem inappropriate to me.

Comment: ***Evangelist***, ***prosthelytizer***.

Comment: \What do you mean by education? General knowledge, or teaching a specific subject? Could you describe the person and what exactly they love teaching. A sample sentence would be especially helpful, I'm not keen on the above suggestions but they might fit if the context is clarified.

Comment: *preacher*.......

Comment: You need to modify the title,(i.e. delete "preach")  otherwise users are just going to suggest the more obvious solutions: *preacher*, *rabbi*, *guru*, *sage*, *spiritual leader*, *mentor*...

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Word for person who loves to share knowledge](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/2975/word-for-person-who-loves-to-share-knowledge)

Comment: It would help if we had the original sentence, and/or as much of that sentence as you had translated, around the word in question.

Comment: @DanBron: Is a _prosthelytizer_ a proselytizer who has an artificial limb?

Comment: @SvenYargs Your comment leaves me paralyzed.

Answer (score 2):

**educationist**  [TFD](https://www.thefreedictionary.com/educationist) or educationalist

an expert in the theory and/or *methods* of education.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not entirely sure a single word would do. 'Enthusiast' certainly fits, but you might want to qualify it further with the subject that enthuses them, such as 'educational/education enthusiast'.

Answer (score 1):

**Pedagogue** can have negative connotations, but depending on the context it might work for you.

https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/pedagogue

Answer (score 1):

**Preceptor** is an oft-neglected age-old word that can be used. I'd also suggest **educationalist**.